# How to get reason for Android DialogFragment onDismiss() being called?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

In my **DialogFragment**, I override `onDismiss()` in order to provide a callback to the parent fragment to notify it when the dialog has been dismissed by the user.

However, `onDismiss()` is also called for config change (e.g., when the device is rotated) - and I do not want a callback in this case.

So I have been trying to find a way to distinguish between `onDismiss()` being called for a user interaction and for a config change, but haven't had any luck.

For each of the two scenarios, these checks return the same values in my `onDismiss()` method:

```
isRemoving() == false
isDetached() == false
isAdded() == true
isInLayout() == false
isVisible() == false
```

I've also tried overriding `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`, but that isn't called at all.

Any ideas how to get the cause of `onDismiss()` being called?

Comment: did you try using `setCancelable(false);` this could avoid `onDismiss()` callback

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that, but it makes no difference.

Comment: If the users dismiss the dialog by pressing BACK or touching the area outside of the dialog window, onCancel() will be called before onDismiss(). If the users dismiss the dialog by clicking a Button, you will be able to catch the click event. So maybe you should override onCancel() instead of onDismiss() and keep track of the click events?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the users dismiss the dialog by pressing BACK or touching the area outside of the dialog window, `onCancel()` will be called before `onDismiss()`.

If the users dismiss the dialog by clicking a `Button`, you will be able to catch the click event.

So you can solve the problem by overriding `onCancel()` instead of `onDismiss()` and keeping track of the click events.

Comment: I am using this solution, and my DialogFragment is delivering its result with `getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult(...)` - see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between#java for more info on that.